# No such user git commit error in Jenkinsfile

Tags: git, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to run **npm version** in a **node:10** Docker container as part of a Jenkinsfile and am getting the following error.

```
npm ERR! fatal: unable to look up current user in the passwd file: no such user
```

Is there a way to allow git to look for the user another way?

Answer (score 2):

Without testing, I can't guarantee this, but it should guide you in the right direction:

Jenkins starts the docker container without a user (using the UID and GID), so you can start it with root (or add a new user in your Dockerfile which is better):

```
agent {
    docker {
        image 'node:10'
        args  '--user root'
    }
}
```

Another option is that you can set these environment variables:

```
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=’user_name’
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=’user_email’
```

You can add these as part of the Jenkinsfile or Dockerfile

Comment: This solution did it for me, as I was using the master as a build agent I added these two variables as Environment Variables in my Deployment